# intercept numerical subdomains and rewrite to example.com/?(number)

Tags: subdomain, url-rewriting

Is there anyway via `.htaccess` to rewrite numerical subdomains to `/?`.

For example, `0123.example.com` would be handled by `example.com/?0123`.

I want a rewrite rule not a redirect because I want to hide that, so the browser still displays `0123.example.com`.  How would I write such a rule?

Comment: If you want to hide that, it isn't a redirect.  You want an internal rewrite.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ..yes... wasn't that what I was asking about?

Comment: Is there an index file that handles home page requests?  Something like `example.com/index.php`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The issue is that i'm using wordpress, so it need to be intercepted first in the .htaccess file..  maybe it's easier to rewrite the ur to example.com/0123, and skip the ?,(questionmark) in the url